# Dynamic generation of Tkinter child toplevel class using eval()

Tags: python, tkinter

I'd like to know if this example is a good enough excuse to use the much maligned eval() function in python.

I've made a Base class of a selection popup window. Because this cycle is quite a common theme in my program I then inherit from it to create selection windows for all sorts of things. Airports, Aircraft, People etc... I just change the information it displays and the query it uses to query the database, which I pass in as variables (not shown here for simplification).

As you can see below, I pass in the name of a "return variable" which will be updated when the selection is confirmed and the child window closes successfully. I've experimented with setattr() but I can't get away from it being a string and throwing an error so I have stuck with the eval() function.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, master = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.pack()
        self.config(width = 400)
        self.create_application()
    
    def create_application(self):
        self.label1 = tk.Label(self, text = "Label 1")
        self.label1.pack()
        self.entry1_string = tk.StringVar()
        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self, state = "readonly",
                                textvariable = self.entry1_string)
        self.entry1.pack()
        self.entry1_select = tk.Button(self, text = "Select...",
                          command = lambda: self.create_entry1_select_window())
        self.entry1_select.pack()
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self, text = "Label 2")
        self.label2.pack()
        self.entry2_string = tk.StringVar()
        self.entry2 = tk.Entry(self, state = "readonly",
                                textvariable = self.entry2_string)
        self.entry2.pack()
        self.entry2_select = tk.Button(self, text = "Select...",
                          command = lambda: self.create_entry2_select_window())
        self.entry2_select.pack()
        
    def create_entry1_select_window(self):
        self.entry1_select_window = AirportSelectWindow(self,
                                             return_variable = "entry1_string")
        self.entry1_select_window.title("Select Entry 1")
        
    def create_entry2_select_window(self):
        self.entry2_select_window = AirportSelectWindow(self,
                                             return_variable = "entry2_string")
        self.entry2_select_window.title("Select Entry 2")

class BaseSelectWindow(tk.Toplevel):
    
    def __init__(self, master = None, return_variable = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.configure(padx = 10, pady = 10)
        self.master = master
        ######### Is this ok?
        self.return_variable_path = eval("self.master."+return_variable)
        ## Just for example. Real thing retrieves values from DB. ##
        self.search_results = ["Heathrow", "O'Hare", "LAX", "Schipol"]
        self.create_base_widgets()
    
    def create_base_widgets(self):
        self.selection_string = tk.StringVar()
        self.selection_data = tk.OptionMenu(self, self.selection_string,
                                            *self.search_results)
        self.selection_data.pack()
        self.selection_button = tk.Button(self, text = "Confirm...",
               command = lambda: self.confirm_selection(self.selection_string))
        self.selection_button.pack()
    
    def confirm_selection(self, selection):
        self.return_variable_path.set(selection.get())
        self.destroy()
        

class AirportSelectWindow(BaseSelectWindow):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Main Window')

    app = Application(root)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Is this cool? It's not a user generated value so it should be secure.

Comment: Why are you passing a string that is the name of an attribute rather than the actual attribute?

Comment: The code snippet above is far shorter than the actual code I'm developing. It was an example in line with SO's policy of posting a small working example. I will attempt what you've suggested below and come back to you. The question I was asking wasn't pertaining to the code above, more about the principle of passing in an expected return variable name so that I can reuse the Base class in the same way in future and save on code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not a good use of `eval`. The only advantage that `eval` has in this context is to make your code more difficult to understand.

You apparently want to send the name of an attribute to the constructor of `AirportSelectWindow`, but your code would be easier to understand if you just pass in the actual variable.

```
class BaseSelectWindow(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, master = None, return_variable = None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.return_variable_path=return_variable
        ...
```

You would then create it like this:

```
def create_entry1_select_window(self):
    self.entry1_select_window = AirportSelectWindow(self,
                                         return_variable = self.entry1_string)
```

Though, instead of `self.return_variable_path` I would use `self.return_variable`. I don't see that `_path` adds clarity, and in fact removes some clarity. I would also change `self.entry1_string` to `self.entry1_var` since the variable represents a `StringVar`, not a string (and likewise for entry2).

Comment: OK, You've taught me something. I didn't realise you could pass through an object and it would "keep track" of it. I'd thought when you passed in "self.entry1_string" the child window would try and call it verbatim and you'd get a "child object has no attribute 'entry1_string'" error, hence why I was trying to call it with "self.master.*widget*". I've made the changes you've suggested and It's worked so thanks very much.

Comment: Hi Bryan, could you help me understand this a bit better? From what I remember from the python documentation I think I can grasp that when the child window is created, am I right in thinking a new namespace is created? So when you pass in the widget into the return variable is it implicitly called “self.master.*widget” anyway? Does the object exist with 2 different references in 2 namespaces or does the child window contain a reference, a bit like a pointer in C?

Comment: @pilky01: No, when you pass in a return variable it is not implicitly called anything. In my example I explicitly named the parameter `return_variable`, and I explicitly save that as `self.return_variable_path`. These are references. There is only one object, with multiple references.